# How to validate if a user has logged in website in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

I have a table in database called Customer, I want to enable them to log in website? Is there any good practice to suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable forms authentication in web.config.

Create a login page, and in login method, validate the user.  Use FormsAuthentication class to set the authentication cookie.

Here is a write up for the [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

If you create an asp.net mvc site project in visual studio, you will see an implementation of authentication.